# How to fix 'File was loaded in the wrong encoding: UTF-8' in an .sfb file?

Tags: android, encoding, sceneform

I'm converting an .obj file to .sfa and .sfb files but I getting an error header saying ***File was loaded in a wrong encoding:'UTF-18'*** after conversion. How do I resolve this issue?

[A sample photo describing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I28A.png)

Comment: I had the same problem. The solution was to export the .obj file again. My guess is that the problem is not in the sceneform but the .obj file.

Comment: Did you find a solution to copy/past a fsb file from one Android Studio project to another ? A similar bug appears. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the updated version of Sceneform. Even if you've download an old project from Github or any other site, make sure the libraries and the plugins are updated to the current version.

Comment: Yeah.. After I updated the Sceneform Libraries, it resolved UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @JudeAsiamah I have used Google Sceneform Tools (Beta) 1.11.1  which is latest but it have same problem..can you help me?